# Iptables и блокировка ботов поисковиков

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

И так, задача забанить ботов  ненужных поисковиков, для  примера пусть будет бинго.
Команда  Iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo kmp --string bing.com -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Проверяем, запись есть:

```
40   DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             STRING match  "bing.com" ALGO name kmp TO 65535
```

Только вот не помогает, из логов Nginx :

```
157.55.39.120-!--!-"-"-!--!-"01/Feb/2021:03:02:06 +0300"-!--!-"GET /siteUrl/ HTTP/1.1"-!--!-"403"-!--!-"125"-!--!-"-"-!--!-"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"-!--!-"1.34"
```

Никаких разрешающих правил нет. Что делаю не так? Сайт на https

Comment: так бань на nginx

Comment: это не вариант, тогда Nginx все равно будет обрабатывать эти запросы,  а не хотелось бы его нагружать. И тут  скорее вопрос в чем проблема с iptables

Comment: проблема со знанием протоколов. А нгингкс справится лучше